# What does NSManagedContext reset do?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Here's my scenario: I have a thread running heavy calculations, saving the results via core data at the end. I have the thread set up with it's own autorelease pool and it's own `NSManagedContext` created within the thread. The user can change the inputs to the calculation on the main thread, in which case the calculation thread is terminated (via regular checks of a `NSLocked` variable) and relaunched with the new inputs. Everything is working fine here.

For performance reasons, the calculation thread doesn't have an undo manager and there is only one context save at the very end. If a termination command is detected I don't want to save the results. Right now I'm just skipping the context save and releasing it, which seems to work fine.

I noticed, however, that there's a reset method for `NSManagedContext`. Apple's documentation on this method isn't very helpful to me. It simply states that it returns the receiver's contents to it's base state and that all the receiver's managed objects are "forgotten".

What does that mean? Is it the equivalent to reverting to the last saved version? Is an undo manager required for proper operation of this method? Any reason I should use this method instead of what I'm doing now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the context to cache changes independent of the context on the main thread, and if you don't want those changes to be recorded, you just throw them out by deleting the "local" context. This is good enough for the scenario you are describing. -reset might be useful if you didn't want to relaunch the background thread, but just start over using the same thread (and context), but with new inputs. Since you launch a new thread (thus creating a new NSManagedObjectContext on it), -reset is probably not very useful for you in this scenario. You already pretty much doing it as Apple recommends in several of their sample codes.

Comment: Good to know I'm following the recommended approach, thanks. So am I right that reset throws away all unsaved changes to the context? In the case of a change to the calculation's inputs I'm exiting and relaunching the thread to prevent multiple calculations from running simultaneously (granted, I could do probably do this without an exit and relaunch), but I may not want to do this in other future applications of core data.

Comment: Yes, it tosses out all NSManagedObjects contained within insertedObjects, updatedOjects, and deletedObjects, and essentially returns it to the same state it was when you created the NSManagedObjectContext.